# Split xlsx file into other xlsx files based on first column with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a large .xlsx file that I want to split into several files based on the first column. The data structure is kinda iffy which complicates it a lot and I am new to excel in python.

Basically I need to create a separate file for every Row starting with "Brand1" (see below) and another for rows starting with "Brand2" and so on. Whats the best way to do this?

```
Brand_name               Sales                 Year
  BRAND1                1000000                2018 
  BRAND1                1100000                2019
  BRAND2                 900000                2018
  BRAND2                 500000                2019
  BRAND3                 200000                2019
  BRAND4                1200000                2019
```

Comment: `for name, group in df.groupby('Brand_name'): group.to_excel(f'{name}.xlsx')`

Comment: reading excel:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html , save excel : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html , create a df for each Brand_name with groupby, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this.

```
# list all the brands (unique values)
brands = list(df['Brand_name'].unique())

# for each brand, we want to filter the dataframe based on the brand name
# and then export it to excel
for brand in brands:
  filtered_df = df[df['Brand_name'] == brand]
  filtered_df.to_excel(brand + '.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: exactly so that you don't have to do this there is `DataFrame.groupby`. this is much slower

Comment: I have voted because I think this is not a good solution, and I would not like anyone to take this type of solution as a reference to solve this type of problem in Pandas.